# Dynamically resizing a button and saving the new location

Tags: vb.net

I want to be able to resize a button during runtime, then have the program permanently store the new location so once I open it again it remembers I moved it.

I have done some research and tinkering but I don't think I have managed to get any substantial code to show anyone.

Comment: First: You want to resize the button, or you want to move it ? If you only resize it, there will be no new location, only new width /height. Second: Please at least provide the code on how you plan to resize the button ... we will not do all your homework.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind a property to a setting and then the application will read that setting at startup and assign the value to the property.  Select your control, open the Properties window and then use the ApplicationSettings node to bind your desired property to a new or existing setting.

Comment: Any idea on how to create button which I can resize during runtime ??

Comment: A `Button` can already be resized.  Simply set its `Size` property.  If you mean that you want to be able to resize it using drag'n'drop then it's still a regular `Button` control and you have to write your own code to handle dragging'n'dropping.

Answer (score 0):

This is another way of saving the location of the button and then loading it

```
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing_3(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    Dim writer As New System.IO.StreamWriter(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp & "\buttonloc.txt")
    writer.Write(Button1.Location.X & "," & Button1.Location.Y)
    writer.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load_3(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try
        Dim str As String() = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp & "\buttonloc.txt").Split({","}, StringSplitOptions.None)
        Button1.Location = New Point(str(0), str(1))
    Catch
    End Try
End Sub
```

Just paste this to yr form's code and change the `Button1` to your button's name

---

As Alex said, by resizing the button, you don't change its location so this code won't change anything it your program